# WP date_query pull posts 2 days ago

Tags: php, wordpress, date, posts, pull

I have this:

```
if( $display_type == 'today' ) {

        $today = getdate() ;

       $args['date_query'] = array( array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['w'],

        ));
```

"w" for "week", "mday" for "one day", "year" for "year".. etc.
So I want to pull latest post for 2 (or 3, 4, 5..) days, not from 7 days (week). But, I must keep this form, just repcele "w" with something else (eg. "2 days ago").
And if can't, how can?

Answer (score 1):

Your question could do with some more information, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$today = getdate() ;
$mday = $today['mday'];
$days = 2; // Collect post for the last 2 days

$args['date_query'] = array(
    array(
        'year'  => $today['year'],
        'month' => $today['mon'],
    ),
    array(
        'day'   => array( $mday - $days, $mday ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    ),
);
```

I constructed this query from the following documentation:

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters